# Why is std::move implemented using std::remove_reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, stdmove

I don't understand very well the `std::move` function

```
template <class T>
typename remove_reference<T>::type&&
move(T&& a)
{
    return a;
}
```

why `remove_reference` ?
could someone give me a simple explanation ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Think about what happens if `T` is an lvalue reference, for example `MyClass &`. In that case, `T &&` would become `MyClass & &&`, and due to *reference collapsing rules*, this would be transformed into `MyClass &` again. To achieve the right result, `typename remove_reference<MyClass&>::type&&` first removes any reference decorations from the type, so `MyClass &` is mapped to `MyClass`, and then the rvalue reference is applied to it, yielding `MyClass &&`.

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly correct, but obviously someone disagrees :)

Comment: Uhm. I wrote the same thing 10 minutes before you and got down-voted.

Comment: @Let: Hm, I would guess your explanation was a little bit too terse for someone unfamiliar with rvalue references, dunno...

Comment: Kind of weird for someone unfamiliar with the topic to downvote an answer. Not that I care. I just wanted to point out that someone disagrees with this explanation.

Answer (score 7):

Because rvalue reference to lvalue reference would decay to lvalue reference, and returing lvalue reference would have different semantics from those you would expect from `move`.

Edit:
Huh, why the downvote? Check out this code:

```
template < typename T > T&& func(T&& x) { return x; }

int main()
{
        int x;

        int &y = func(x);
}
```

Further reading: http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/cplusplus/rvalue_references_and_perfect_forwarding.html